# Get path to dir by file path

Tags: php

I want to rename file name, for example file is in:

```
/home/vhost/image.png
```

I want to rename file as:

```
/home/vhost/randomname.png
```

(ext can be different)

I wrote little script which matches extension of file and stcks new name with extension.

However, I have problem with directiories. Is there any PHP function where will return path like `'/home/vhost'` for input`'/home/vhost/image.png'` ?
Or should I manually write this script?

Comment: try `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` are you writing a code for file uploading ?

Comment: The function you're looking for is: [`dirname()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)

Comment: @RakeshShetty yep, I'm writin uploading. dirname() works for me. 

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dirname like this:

```
<?php
$path = "/etc/passwd";
$file = dirname ($path); // $file = "/etc"
?>
```